# Blending material seams?

Tags: materials

I've been working on this mushroom to render and the stalk and dome create a seam where there is different materials. Anyone know how to fix this?[image]

Answer (score -1):

[Divide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U3J-oYFdyqQ) your stalk and dome into two separate objects, then assign one material to stalk and another one to the dome.

Comment: I have the materials assigned to different groups. I may have worded the question wrong, i am wondering how to blur or blend the hard edge that is made when the materials are next to eachother.

Comment: You don't need to [separate into objects to assign different material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516)